# ¿Cómo solucionar un EOFError: EOF when reading a line en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

¿me podrías ayudar con esto?  Sucede que se ejecuta correctamente en PyCharman, pero me indica ese error al colocarlo en una página, me es obligatorio subirlo ahí. Gracias de antemano

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        sum = sum + lista[i]
    x = sum/len(lista)

    sumw = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        sumw = sumw + (lista[i] - x)**2
    y = (sumw/(len(lista)))**0.5
    return (x, y)


el = input("Ingrese los valores:")
lista = el.split(",")

for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = float(lista[i])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sé a qué página lo subes, pero esa página no admite la entrada de datos por teclado en la forma normal. Es decir, `input()` no funciona. Quizás esa página tiene algún otro mecanismo para pedir datos. En cualquier caso también puedes asignar un valor a `el` a modo de ejemplo, en vez de pedírselo al usuario. Por ejemplo podrías poner `el="1,2,4,3,7,5"`

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con número te recomiendo que los conviertas a enteros con ```int()``` ya que ```input``` te devuelve un String

Comment: @christian no es ese el problema, su código divide correctamente la cadena por las comas para obtener una lista y luego pasa cada elemento a `float`

Comment: @abulafia tienes razón no me había percatado de esa línea

Comment: Gracias @abulafia e igualmente a Christian